# How can I get the value of two attributes and put it in another attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a multiple calendar table and I want to combine all attribute in another attribute. Is it possible or not? Just experimenting. Here's a sample code of the *** HTML ***

```
<div class="day_num" data-date="17" date="July 2019">17</div>
```

I want to put the `data-date` and `date` attribute to this div attribute:

```
<div full-date=""></div>
```

Is this possible? sorry for experimenting such thing.

*** This is a sample calendar ***

[image]

Every cell has the `div` mention above. I will include the `HTML` output

[image]

Comment: <div full-date=""> - This div is at multiple places? Number of ".day_num" element === number of "attr[full-date]"? All are in same loop?

Comment: @HardikChaudhary yes sir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will loop through day_num elements, combine its attribute to form the date & assign that date to the child div into the full-date attribute.

```
$('.day_num').each(function(){
    let full_date = $(this).attr('data-date')+' '+$(this).attr('date');
    $(this).children('div').attr('full-date',full_date);
})
```

Answer (score 3):

The attribute values are plain strings, which can be combined (concatenated) together as you want, using the `+` operator. I assume you would want to put "17 July 2019" as the full-date attribute (assuming here your elements have and ID tags "source" and "target", to make sure the selector returns a single element):

```
let day = $("#source").attr("data-date");
let date = $("#source").attr("date");
let fullDate = day + " " + date;
$("#target").attr("full-date", fullDate);
```

Edit: With the full HTML and table in the question; You'll need to loop over the elements `$(".day_num")`, and apply the same piece of code to each fragment:

```
$(".day_num").each(function () {
    let $this = $(this);
    let day = $this.attr("data-date");
    let date = $this.attr("date");
    let fullDate = day + " " + date;
    $this.find("div").attr("full-date", fullDate);
});
```

Comment: but it is a table sir or should i say a calendar table and every cell of the table has that divs sir.

Comment: if i just do that the output will be this `<div full-date="July 2019 1"></div>` the first number of the cell will be called.

Comment: I updated my question sir. And put the output `HTML` code.

Comment: Updated my answer; you'll need a loop.

Comment: These works too ^_^ super thank you... You guys made my day! I've got many ways to do. Thank you @vlumi